# How to set default printer for new users using powershell

Tags: powershell, printing, default

Have a question on how to set the default printer for NEW users via powershell.

I have seen many posts about setting the default printer via the wmi method.  This seems to work only for the currently logged in user that is running it.  This will not work for other users that may have already logged in.  I can set the default printer for user sid already in the profile list in the registry via `HKU:\<SID>\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows` key.  I set the device string to the printer name and port, `isMRUEstablished` i set to `0` and `legacydefaultprintermode` i set to `1` to prevent windows from setting the last used printer as default.  This seems to work for any users that have already logged on.  Issue is i cant seem to find a way to set it system wide.  If install the printer and set it up before the user gets the machine and logs in for the first time it wont be set for them.  I have tried making the above mentioned registry changes to the `.defualt` user registry hive but when a new person logs into that machine they have something like webex document print set to the default or onenote printer or something else.  Is there any other way to set via powershell so it will apply to a new user that logs  on?

Comment: Looks like windows 10 doesnt let you set defaults via registry.  I can use the .default registry profile to set the device but if set LegacyDefaultPrinterMode to 1 which is enabled, under the .default profile it does not carry over to the new login profile.  The user profile will have the printer set in the device key but with LegacyDefaultPrinterMode set to 0.  So when the user logins there will be no default because the user has not selected a printer yet.  Looks like the only way to manage this setting is via group policy.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the hive from the default profile found in c:\users\default and called ntuser.dat.

After loading this hive make the reg setting as needed. Then unload the hive. Now anyone who logs in to the system for the first time will get those settings, whatever they are, by default. The .Default in the registry is what runs when the system is at login but not yet logged in so no effect for printer settings.

Comment: Pretty sure I tried that.  Mentioned it above but would have to go back and check it again.  Been too long since I messed with it.  I gave up on it and just left it to the user to set I think and moved on.